# How to show background image between sections of page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to show gaps between sections of a webpage, where the background image 
shows through in the gaps, like in the following:

[example website picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0cGm.jpg)

[Link to website](http://www.foodsthatdogood.com.au/)

Is it possible to do this with CSS?

I'm not sure how to properly word the effect that I'm going for.

Cheers

edit. source code from wordpress theme, ugh

```html
<body class="page-template page-template-full-width page-template-full-width-php page page-id-17 logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support mkdf-bmi-calculator-1.0 mkd-core-1.1 mkdf-boxed wellspring-ver-1.4 mkdf-smooth-scroll  mkdf-ajax mkdf-grid-1000 mkdf-header-standard mkdf-sticky-header-on-scroll-up mkdf-default-mobile-header mkdf-sticky-up-mobile-header mkdf-menu-item-first-level-bg-color mkdf-dropdown-default mkdf-large-title-text wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-5.0.1 vc_responsive">



<div class="mkdf-wrapper">
    <div class="mkdf-wrapper-inner">
     
 
 <div class="mkdf-top-bar">
    <div class="mkdf-grid">
         <div class="mkdf-vertical-align-containers mkdf-30-30-30">
    <div class="mkdf-position-left mkdf-top-bar-widget-area">
     <div class="mkdf-position-left-inner mkdf-top-bar-widget-area-inner">
             <div id="text-3" class="widget widget_text mkdf-top-bar-widget"><div class="mkdf-top-bar-widget-inner">   <div class="textwidget"><a href="mailto:info@achievecompletehealth.com.au"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
info@achievecompletehealth.com.au</a></div>
  </div></div>           </div>
    </div>
         <div class="mkdf-position-center mkdf-top-bar-widget-area">
      <div class="mkdf-position-center-inner mkdf-top-bar-widget-area-inner">
             </div>
     </div>
        <div class="mkdf-position-right mkdf-top-bar-widget-area">
     <div class="mkdf-position-right-inner mkdf-top-bar-widget-area-inner">
             
     <div id="mkd_social_icon_widget-4" class="widget widget_mkd_social_icon_widget mkdf-top-bar-widget"><div class="mkdf-top-bar-widget-inner">
        <a class="mkdf-social-icon-widget-holder"  style="color: #006489" href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/achievecompletehealth/" target="_blank">
            <i class="mkdf-social-icon-widget fa fa-facebook"></i>        </a>

     </div></div>               </div>
    </div>
   </div>
     </div>
  </div>

 

<header class="mkdf-page-header">
        <div class="mkdf-menu-area">
                    <div class="mkdf-grid">
                       <div class="mkdf-vertical-align-containers">
                <div class="mkdf-position-left">
                    <div class="mkdf-position-left-inner">
                                            </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mkdf-position-right">
                    <div class="mkdf-position-right-inner">
                        
<nav class="mkdf-main-menu mkdf-drop-down mkdf-default-nav">
    <ul id="menu-logged-in-menu" class="clearfix"><li id="nav-menu-item-179" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home  narrow"><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Home</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
<li id="nav-menu-item-180" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-17 current_page_item mkdf-active-item narrow"><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/about/" class=" current "><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">About</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
<li id="nav-menu-item-181" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page  narrow"><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/testimonials/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Testimonials</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
<li id="nav-menu-item-182" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page  narrow"><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/program/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Program</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
<li id="nav-menu-item-184" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page  narrow"><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/cm-loss/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Measuring Loss</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
<li id="nav-menu-item-185" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page  narrow"><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/tips-tricks-for-losing-belly-fat/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Tips &#038; Tricks</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
<li id="nav-menu-item-268" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children  has_sub narrow"><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/what-you-need-to-know/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">What you need to know</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a>
<div class="second " ><div class="inner"><ul  >
 <li id="nav-menu-item-270" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/meal-plans/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Meal Plans</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
 <li id="nav-menu-item-347" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/vegetarian-meal-plans/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Vegetarian Meal Plans</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
 <li id="nav-menu-item-269" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/approved-foods/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Approved Foods</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
 <li id="nav-menu-item-271" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/product-instructions/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Product Instructions</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
 <li id="nav-menu-item-346" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/faqs/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">FAQs</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
</ul></div></div>
</li>
<li id="nav-menu-item-183" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page  narrow"><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/contact-us/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Contact Us</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
<li id="nav-menu-item-306" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom  narrow"><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/wp-login.php?action=logout&#038;redirect_to=index.php&#038;_wpnonce=f2738e25f6" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Log Out</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
</ul></nav>

                                            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
<div class="mkdf-sticky-header">
        <div class="mkdf-sticky-holder">
            <div class="mkdf-grid">
                        <div class=" mkdf-vertical-align-containers">
                <div class="mkdf-position-left">
                    <div class="mkdf-position-left-inner">
                                            </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mkdf-position-right">
                    <div class="mkdf-position-right-inner">
                     
<nav class="mkdf-main-menu mkdf-drop-down mkdf-sticky-nav">
    <ul id="menu-logged-in-menu-1" class="clearfix"><li id="sticky-nav-menu-item-179" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home  narrow"><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Home</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
<li id="sticky-nav-menu-item-180" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-17 current_page_item mkdf-active-item narrow"><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/about/" class=" current "><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">About</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
<li id="sticky-nav-menu-item-181" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page  narrow"><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/testimonials/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Testimonials</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
<li id="sticky-nav-menu-item-182" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page  narrow"><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/program/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Program</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
<li id="sticky-nav-menu-item-184" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page  narrow"><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/cm-loss/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Measuring Loss</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
<li id="sticky-nav-menu-item-185" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page  narrow"><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/tips-tricks-for-losing-belly-fat/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Tips &#038; Tricks</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
<li id="sticky-nav-menu-item-268" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children  has_sub narrow"><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/what-you-need-to-know/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">What you need to know</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a>
<div class="second " ><div class="inner"><ul>
 <li id="sticky-nav-menu-item-270" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/meal-plans/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Meal Plans</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
 <li id="sticky-nav-menu-item-347" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/vegetarian-meal-plans/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Vegetarian Meal Plans</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
 <li id="sticky-nav-menu-item-269" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/approved-foods/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Approved Foods</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
 <li id="sticky-nav-menu-item-271" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/product-instructions/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Product Instructions</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
 <li id="sticky-nav-menu-item-346" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/faqs/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">FAQs</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
</ul></div></div>
</li>
<li id="sticky-nav-menu-item-183" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page  narrow"><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/contact-us/" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Contact Us</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
<li id="sticky-nav-menu-item-306" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom  narrow"><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/wp-login.php?action=logout&#038;redirect_to=index.php&#038;_wpnonce=f2738e25f6" class=""><span class="item_outer"><span class="item_inner"><span class="item_text">Log Out</span></span><span class="plus"></span></span></a></li>
</ul></nav>

                                            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
</div>

</header>


<header class="mkdf-mobile-header">
    <div class="mkdf-mobile-header-inner">
                <div class="mkdf-mobile-header-holder">
            <div class="mkdf-grid">
                <div class="mkdf-vertical-align-containers">
                                            <div class="mkdf-mobile-menu-opener">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <span class="mkdf-mobile-opener-icon-holder">
                        <i class="mkdf-icon-font-awesome fa fa-bars " ></i>                    </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                                                            <div class="mkdf-position-right">
                        <div class="mkdf-position-right-inner">
                                                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- close .mkdf-vertical-align-containers -->
            </div>
        </div>
        
<nav class="mkdf-mobile-nav">
    <div class="mkdf-grid">
        <ul id="menu-logged-in-menu-2" class=""><li id="mobile-menu-item-179" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/" class=""><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li id="mobile-menu-item-180" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-17 current_page_item mkdf-active-item"><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/about/" class=" current "><span>About</span></a></li>
<li id="mobile-menu-item-181" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/testimonials/" class=""><span>Testimonials</span></a></li>
<li id="mobile-menu-item-182" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/program/" class=""><span>Program</span></a></li>
<li id="mobile-menu-item-184" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/cm-loss/" class=""><span>Measuring Loss</span></a></li>
<li id="mobile-menu-item-185" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/tips-tricks-for-losing-belly-fat/" class=""><span>Tips &#038; Tricks</span></a></li>
<li id="mobile-menu-item-268" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children  has_sub"><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/what-you-need-to-know/" class=""><span>What you need to know</span></a><span class="mobile_arrow"><i class="mkdf-sub-arrow fa fa-angle-right"></i><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
<ul class="sub_menu">
 <li id="mobile-menu-item-270" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/meal-plans/" class=""><span>Meal Plans</span></a></li>
 <li id="mobile-menu-item-347" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/vegetarian-meal-plans/" class=""><span>Vegetarian Meal Plans</span></a></li>
 <li id="mobile-menu-item-269" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/approved-foods/" class=""><span>Approved Foods</span></a></li>
 <li id="mobile-menu-item-271" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/product-instructions/" class=""><span>Product Instructions</span></a></li>
 <li id="mobile-menu-item-346" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/faqs/" class=""><span>FAQs</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="mobile-menu-item-183" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/contact-us/" class=""><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
<li id="mobile-menu-item-306" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom "><a href="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/wp-login.php?action=logout&#038;redirect_to=index.php&#038;_wpnonce=f2738e25f6" class=""><span>Log Out</span></a></li>
</ul>    </div>
</nav>

    </div>
</header> <!-- close .mkdf-mobile-header -->



                 <a id='mkdf-back-to-top'  href='#'>
                <span class="mkdf-icon-stack">
                     <span aria-hidden="true" class="mkdf-icon-font-elegant arrow_carrot-up " ></span>                </span>
                  <span class="mkdf-back-to-top-inner">
                    <span class="mkdf-back-to-top-text">Top</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        
        <div class="mkdf-content" >
                        <div class="mkdf-content-inner">
    <div class="mkdf-title mkdf-standard-type mkdf-preload-background mkdf-has-background mkdf-has-parallax-background mkdf-content-center-alignment mkdf-animation-right-left mkdf-title-image-not-responsive" style="color:#ffffff;;background-image:url(http://localhost/ach/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/dusk-925015_1280.jpg);;height:250px;" data-height="250" data-background-width=&quot;1280&quot;>
        <div class="mkdf-title-image"><img src="http://localhost/ach/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/dusk-925015_1280.jpg" alt="&nbsp;" /> </div>
        <div class="mkdf-title-holder" style="height:250px;">
            <div class="mkdf-container clearfix">
                <div class="mkdf-container-inner">
                    <div class="mkdf-title-subtitle-holder" style="">
                        <div class="mkdf-title-subtitle-holder-inner">
                                                                                   <h1 style="color:#ffffff;"><span>About</span></h1>
                                                                                                                                                 </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<div class="mkdf-full-width">
<div class="mkdf-full-width-inner">
      <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid mkdf-section vc_custom_1492473523647 mkdf-content-aligment-left" style=""><div class="clearfix mkdf-full-section-inner"><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12"><div class="vc_column-inner "><div class="wpb_wrapper"><div data-original-height="32" class="vc_empty_space"  style="height: 32px" ><span class="vc_empty_space_inner"></span></div>

 <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
   <p class="font_8" style="text-align: justify;">Our program has been specially designed to balance your hormones during the detox phase to actually teach your body to lose weight. We rest and repair the gut by mono-eating during this phase, the low calorie intake is sustainable because we support your body with the best nutrition on the market.</p>
<p class="font_8" style="text-align: justify;">If you are looking to lose 10kg -15kg in 30 days this program is for  you, and it can be done over again if you have more weight to lose.</p>
<p class="font_8" style="text-align: justify;">This program also helps many people with depression, skin disorders, high blood pressure, Diabetes, problems conceiving and countless other ailments.</p>
<p class="font_8" style="text-align: justify;">There are no shakes, it&#8217;s real food &#8211; protein &amp; vegetables.</p>
<p class="font_8" style="text-align: justify;">We offer support by way of an online group, and an individual mentor to help you stay on track. No one does this program alone.</p>

  </div>
 </div>
</div></div></div></div></div>
       </div>
</div>
</div> <!-- close div.content_inner -->
</div>  <!-- close div.content -->

<footer class="mkdf-page-footer">
 <div class="mkdf-footer-inner clearfix">

  
<div class="mkdf-footer-top-holder">
 <div class="mkdf-footer-top mkdf-footer-top-aligment-left">
  
  <div class="mkdf-container">
   <div class="mkdf-container-inner">

  <div class="mkdf-four-columns clearfix">
 <div class="mkdf-four-columns-inner">
  <div class="mkdf-column">
   <div class="mkdf-column-inner">
       </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mkdf-column">
   <div class="mkdf-column-inner">
       </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mkdf-column">
   <div class="mkdf-column-inner">
       </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mkdf-column">
   <div class="mkdf-column-inner">
       </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mkdf-footer-bottom-holder">
 <div class="mkdf-footer-bottom-holder-inner">
     <div class="mkdf-container">
    <div class="mkdf-container-inner">

  <div class="mkdf-three-columns clearfix">
 <div class="mkdf-three-columns-inner">
  <div class="mkdf-column">
   <div class="mkdf-column-inner">
    <div id="text-7" class="widget mkdf-footer-bottom-left widget_text">   <div class="textwidget"></div>
  </div>   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mkdf-column">
   <div class="mkdf-column-inner">
    <div id="text-6" class="widget mkdf-footer-text widget_text">   <div class="textwidget">Copyright Achieve Complete Health 2017. </div>
  </div><div id="text-9" class="widget mkdf-footer-text widget_text">   <div class="textwidget">See a copy of our full disclaimer <a href="">here</a>.</div>
  </div>   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mkdf-column">
   <div class="mkdf-column-inner">
    <div id="text-8" class="widget mkdf-footer-bottom-left widget_text">   <div class="textwidget"></div>
  </div>   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>    </div>
   </div>
    </div>
 </div>

 </div>
</footer>

</div> <!-- close div.mkdf-wrapper-inner  -->
</div> <!-- close div.mkdf-wrapper -->
```

Comment: I already found gaps there. Which sections do you mean?

Comment: The link is not my site, I want to achieve this on the site I am building. Like the gap between the menu and content, the background shows through.

Comment: Got it. Please add the source code to be changed.

Comment: Yeah its a wordpress theme, so that looks messy af

Answer (score 1):

You can using "padding" property to achieve this
like padding:10%;

Answer (score 1):

They're using style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px" you use the same.